# Basic implementation of EIP-2981

Tags: blockchain, ethereum, solidity

Can somebody share with me a basic implementation of EIP-2981 on solidity?
https://eips.ethereum.org/EIPS/eip-2981#examples

Answer (score 2):

The [EIP-2981](https://eips.ethereum.org/EIPS/eip-2981) is still in the Draft status. Which means it's still being defined and redefined, there haven't been any (official) voting or even peer review from the core team.

It's possible to implement standards defined by EIPs that do not propose any changes to the network (and they only propose contract standards such as token standards). But it's very rare to see these drafts implemented, because there's a high probability that they'll get changed multiple times before they're finally approved or rejected.

And it seems that there's no (well-known) implementation of this particular draft.

For more info about the EIP statuses, see the [EIP homepage](https://eips.ethereum.org/).